# Formatting SQL server results

Tags: excel, powershell, powershell-3.0

Here is my query to execute against sql server and store result in Excel.

What I am not able to achieve is

1) Making headers font size 16 and bold.

2) Headers background color blue.

3) And all the records be bordered.

4) There is a column called Status which shows success, failure. I want that in color suppose failure red, success green

```
   $query = "Select   [Job Name],(SUBSTRING(run_duration, 1, 2) + ':' +  SUBSTRING(run_duration, 3, 2) + ':' +
    SUBSTRING(run_duration, 5, 2)) AS run_duration,run_date ,

    (SUBSTRING(run_Time, 1, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(run_Time, 3, 2) + ':' +
    SUBSTRING(run_Time, 5, 2)) AS [Job _Started Time]

     from  (

        Select k.name as [Job Name], run_date,
    [run_duration] = ((RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(varchar(6), run_duration), 6))),
    ((RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(varchar(6), run_Time), 6))) as
    Run_Time from Msdb..sysjobhistory j inner join msdb ..sysjobs k
        on  K.job_ID=j.Job_ID
        Where run_date=CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 112)  and step_id=0
        ) a "
    Get-process *Excel* |Stop-process
      $csvFilePath = "c:\Powershell\Jobs.csv"
       $excelFilePath = "c:\Powershell\Jobs1.xls"

      write-host "Executing query against server: Localhost " 
    $results = Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $query 

    write-host "Saving Query Results in CSV format..."
      $results | export-csv  $csvFilePath   -NoTypeInformation

         write-host "Converting CSV output to Excel..."
      $excel = New-Object -ComObject excel.application
       $excel.visible = $true
      $excel.displayalerts=$False
       $workbook = $excel.Workbooks.Open($csvFilePath)

      $workSheet = $workbook.worksheets.Item(1)
        $resize = $workSheet.UsedRange
      $resize.EntireColumn.AutoFit() | Out-Null
      $xlExcel8 = 56
     $workbook.SaveAs($excelFilePath,$xlExcel8)
      $Sheet = $excel.WorkSheets.Item(1)
     $excel = $null


    write-host "Results are saved in Excel file: " $excelFilePath

       Get-process *Excel* |stop-Process -verbose
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing well so far to have made it that far. Personally I prefer to use the PowerShell Community Extensions, and thus have access to `Out-Clipboard` and can just "copy" from PowerShell and paste into Excel without having to create a CSV file first. That's my preference, take it or leave it, it has no real standing on your questions at hand.

What you want to be done can be done with just a few lines of script. You probably want this before you auto-size your columns, since increasing the font size may mess with that. First we want to select the area that's in use:

```
$range = $workbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange
```

Ok, easy enough. Then let's get a sub-range of that for just the first row, where your titles are:

```
$TitleRow = $range.Rows|?{$_.row -eq 1}
```

All right, now to modify the `.Font` and `.Interior` properties for size and color:

```
$TitleRow.Font.Size = 16
$TitleRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 5 #Depends on the default color palate, but the standard one makes this blue
```

Lastly we will apply a border using the `Range.BorderAround` method. Now, the method uses a few parameters which are Line Style, Line Weight, and Line Color. For Style, 1 = Continuous (vs dotted, dashed, etc.). For Weight, 2 = Thin, which is default. For Color, 0 = Black.

```
$range.BorderAround(1,2,0)
```

And there you have it, title row has a size 16 font, and a background color of blue, and the entire area has a border around it.

Now, the Failure/Success bit is a bit more challenging. First we need to find the Status column, so let's search the cells in the range for the word Status, and make sure it's in the first row, and grab that column number:

```
$Status = $range.cells|?{$_.row -eq 1 -and $_.value2 -match "status"}|select -ExpandProperty Column
```

Ok, now to adjust each cell in that column. I'm going to run a ForEach loop, processing each cell in the column number where we found the Status title. In that loop I will make sure that the cell we are adjusting is not the first row (so as not to mess with the title row), and then if it matches the text of "Failure" color it red, else color it green (again making sure it isn't the title row):

```
foreach($Cell in ($range.Columns | ?{$_.column -eq $status}).Cells){
    if($Cell.value2 -match "Failure" -and !($Cell.Row -eq 1)){
        $Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    }elseif(!($Cell.Row -eq 1)){
        $Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    }
}
```

And there you go, formatted as desired.